# Designing header with bootstrap (image, text & search)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a header using bootstrap. I want to put a logo at the top, to the right of it, that is, at the header. And I want to place a bootstrap search bar at the right of the entire header. I've tried to float the search bar right, but however it gets placed right after the header text. So the image, header text and the search bar come one after the other and hence when I keep minimizing the browser window, they do not stack properly either according to bootstrap's responsive layout.

```
<div class="container">
        <img src="http://www.computerclipart.com/computer_clipart_images/cartoon_computer_and_books_0521-1004-3015-4128_SMU.jpg" height="90" width="120" />
        <h1 class="logo"> Resource Directory
        <form class="form-search pull-right">
                <div class="input-append">
                        <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                </div>
        </form>
        </h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="container" style="width: auto">
                                       <!-- Nav Bar Contents goes here, removed it to minimize the code -->
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="hero-unit">
                <h2><center>XYZ University - Academic Resource Directory</center></h2>
        Welcome to the Academic Resource Directory of XYZ University. All the resources related to academics can be found here!
        </div>

        <hr>

        <footer>
                <p>&#169; Copy 2012</p>
        </footer>
</div>
```

And here is another custom made css file I added.

```
h1 {
font-size:1.8em;
}
h2 {
    font-size:1.4em;
}

img {
    float: left;
}

.logo {
    font:2.5em Arial;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding-top: 35px;
    width:auto;
    color:#000;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;

}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family:Arial;
font-size:0.8em;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

When I try to float right, sometimes it comes in between the text and the image too or below the text. I want image at the left, text to the right of the image and search bar at the right end of the header aligned along the text. Please help me design my header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the search form enclosed in your `<H1>`. Fix this then move forward with your CSS changes.

```
<h1 class="logo"> Resource Directory <!-- </h1> should be here -->
    <form class="form-search pull-right">
            <div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
            </div>
    </form>
</h1><!-- Move </h1> so your form isn't enclosed -->
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that and then the search bar moved to the top right corner. Inspected with firebug element and made the padding-top: 40px in the bootstrap.min.css file in .input append class. Hope this helps someone. And thanks a lot Michael.